# como modificar arraylist

Tags: javascript, java, array, lista, arraylist

necesito poder modificar los atributos de un arraylist. Tengo un array llamado automoviles y los atributos y constructores estan en una clase llamada consecionario. en el codigo es el "case 5" que necesito apoyo. ubicar un de los objetos que ya ingrese y modificar esos mismos.

```
                break;
                  //caso 5, en el que necesito ayuda                 
                case 5:

                    System.out.println("¿Que vehiculo desea editar?");
                    int editar = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
                    //obtener objeto
                    automoviles.get(editar);
                    String carro1= new nuevo_vehiculo ;

                    automoviles.remove(editar);
                    System.out.println("ingrese el nuevo color");
                    String colornuevo = entrada.readLine();
                    automoviles.add(colornuevo);
                    automoviles.set(editar, colornuevo);


                        break;
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }while(opcion != 6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo un ArrayList de Strings, pero ¿no has pensado en hacer un ArrayList de un objeto llamado carro? Por ejemplo

```java
 public class Carro(){
        private String color;
        private String marca;

        public void setColor(String color){
            this.color = color;
       }

       public void setMarca(String marca){
            this.marca = marca;
       }

       public String getColor (){
            return this.color;
       }

       public String getMarca (){
            return this.marca;
       }
}
```

Ok, listo, ya puedes crear un ArrayList de objetos Carro

```java
ArrayList<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<Carro>();

// para añadir un carro

Carro newcarro = new Carro();
newcarro.setColor("negro");
newcarro.setMarca("bmw");

carros.add(carro); 

// podrias guardar una variable en el arreglo que te indique el ID del carro
// que logras con eso? puede iterar todo el arreglo hasta que la ID del carro concuerde, ejemplo

for(int i=0; i < carros.size(); i++){
    // suponiendo que la clase tiene un metodo getID y estas buscando el ID 5
    if(carros.get(i).getID == 5){
        Carro carroselect = carros.get(i);
        carroselect.setColor("newcolor");
        carroselect.setMarca("otramarca");
        carros.set(i, carroselect);
    }
}
```

espero haberte ayudado !